# Shopware 6 Custom Storefront Controller header image

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I created a custom controller, which works fine except one case.

when i clear the cache/compile the theme and load the storefront with my controller as first, then the header logo and the favicon are not correct. the shop tries to load some, to my point of view, non existing images. when i clear the cache and load any other page first, then it all works fine.

even if i take all i do in that controller out and just load via PageLoader the default stuff, this happens. i can repeat it whenever i want.

if i load any other page fist, everything is fine. and its only the header and favicon that is missing. the rest is always working like it should.

when its laoding correct, the image path is

/media/e3/8c/4f/1694073595/logo.png

and when its not, then the path is

/media/f8/4b/82/1694066395/logo.png

and i have no idea whre that path comes from, such file does not exist at all, nowhere in the media manager

Comment: I tried so many things here. In the end it seems to have helped, that i removed the theme media, created a new folder which i made the default theme media folder. removed that folder and made the original theme media folder again the default theme media folder. then i added the media again and now its working. after every of the above steps i cleared the caches. After hours of searching for the error it seems to be fixed.